# Timing Functions in c++: The most accurate approach

Tags: c++, timing

I'd like to time each function in my code. So I have

```
func1(); 
func2();
func3();
```

At the moment I'm using

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <time.h>

double start1=omp_get_wtime();
func1(); 
double end1=omp_get_wtime();
cout<<"\nfunc1 run time :"<<end1-start1<<endl;


double start2=omp_get_wtime();
func2(); 
double end2=omp_get_wtime();
cout<<"\nfunc2 run time :"<<end2-start2<<endl;
...
```

**Question:** Is there any better and more accurate way than I'm using to measure run time for each function?

Comment: Timings can be noisy, so a good thing to do (where possible) is to run the functions several times and take the best result.

Comment: @TomSeddon sure, I'll do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ recently (i.e., standard C++11) introduced `std::chrono` for getting timing information. This is a cross-platform mechanism. See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono). If you have a modern compiler, you can use it as follows:

```
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> t;
t = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
```

Prior than C++11, C++ did not contain any timing facility and you add to rely on either

- mechanisms provided by the operating system; on Linux you can use  `clock_gettime()`
- mechanism provided by the hardware platform (e.g., [x86 TSC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter))

Which is the most accurate mechanism depends on your specific operating system and hardware platform.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'll have a try.